# OpenCV Python - How to use Cascade Classifier on GPU

Tags: opencv, gpu

I am using opencv and its  included HaarCascade classifiers to do a head detection. I am using the python interface to opencv and following this tutorial:
[OpenCV Face Detection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html#face-detection)

I could see from the opencv documentation that you can use GPU to speed up the Cascadeclassifier. However, I could not find any tutorial or example on how to do this in python. Can anyone help me with this. I am currently using opencv from anaconda which is only at 2.4.11. But I can download and try other versions if the GPU support is specific to the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

This [repo](https://github.com/alexanderkoumis/opencv-gpu-py) seems to do what you want.